# SQL get the active users based on the join and leave date

Tags: sql-server

I have the following table:

**Person**

- userID
- Name
- date_created
- date_left

My rows:

```
-- Datetime format MM-DD-YYYY
userID  Name    date_created    date_left
1       aa      01-01-2018      NULL
2       bb      01-01-2018      11-15-2018
3       cc      06-20-2018      NULL
4       dd      03-03-2018      11-13-2018
5       ee      11-08-2018      11-30-2018
6       ff      12-01-2018      NULL
```

I also have a invoice period date (month and year).

What I'm trying to do is to get a list of active users **based on the invoice period!**.

**MY IDEAL RESULT:**

If invoice month = 11 and year = 2018:

users 1,3,5 should be shown

**Reason user 5 is selected:**
If a user join and leaves in the same month, he is seen as active **but** if a user leaves on the month and has a join date smaller than the invoice month, it's not active (since it left on the month of invoicing but joined earlier)

if invoice month = 12 and year = 2018:

users 1,3,6 should be shown

**Therefor:**

I also want to retrieve the results for the users that are already left (and check if they were active based on the passed month and year). This means that I also want to be able to dynamically check the users that were active

This is my query:

```
  GO
  DECLARE @month int, @year int;

  SET @month = 12;
  SET @year = 2018;

  SELECT * FROM PERSON
  WHERE (month(date_created) = @month -1 ) OR (MONTH(date_created) < @month AND YEAR(date_created)  = @year AND date_left = null)
```

but this still returns everyone.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide sample query to generate the underlying data?

Comment: And It would be better if you add expected and current result!

Comment: i added some information at the end @PrashantPimpale

Comment: `date_created field equal to the passed month` ?? or less than passed month?  Your logic isnt clear because your data neither date is on november

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza i have updated my question, sorry for the confusion

Comment: You share your ideal result, but dont explain the logic why the records are selected. We can try to guess, But as you seen the interpretetion vary and we waste our time guessing.

Comment: Next time try to use ANSI date format YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza i agree with your point and apologize for the confusion, i have updated the question as precisely as i could and hope it's clear for the persons trying to help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
DECLARE @month int, @year int, @dateToCheck datetime;

SET @month = 12;
SET @year = 2018;
SET @dateToCheck = dateadd(month, 1, datefromparts(@year, @month, 1))

SELECT * 
FROM PERSON
WHERE date_created < @dateToCheck
  AND (date_left is null or date_left >= @dateToCheck)
```

So if your month is 11 and year 2018 @datetocheck will be 2018-12-01 and you will get anyone created on or before 2018-11-30 and have a null date_left or a date left on or after 2018-12-01.

If your month is 12 and year 2018, @datetocheck will be 2018-12-31 and you will get anyone created on or before 2018-12-31 and that have a date_left = null or a date left on or after 2019-01-01

Comment: I think this work, but you need calculate `month -1` to compare against  `date_created`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza are you sure that is needed ? since the query also needs to be working if `month = 1` and `year = 2019`

Comment: Yes, you substract from `@dateToCheck` not from `@month`. Anyway  that is OP requirement

Comment: @MikeS your query does not include the persons created in december if their creation date is in december

Comment: `SET @dateCreatedCheck =  DATEADD(month, -1, @dateToCheck)`

Comment: Subtracting a month from @dateToCheck will include only users who are created before the November 1st. You need to be really clear what you are wanting: Given December 2018 you want all users created during December 2018 or before and that haven't left by December 1st 2018? So if someone was created december 2nd but left on december 10th you don't want them but if they were created November 30th and left Jan 1, 2019 you do?

Comment: @MikeS thanks for your comment! i added the ideal results in my original question. sorry for the misconfusion

Comment: I've adjusted the query accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to compare with the current date. Then try like this

```
SELECT * FROM Person
WHERE DATEDIFF(m,date_created,GETDATE())=1 AND date_left IS NULL
```

The active users are considered as the one who is date_created is a month before